# Versioning file name using Python

Tags: python, version-control

Basically when I download a file, it should check whether the file exists or not. If not exits rename the file with the version-0 else if exists rename the file with the next iterating version (eg- it should be file-name-version-1)

Here is what I have tried:

```
def VersionFile(file_spec, vtype='copy'):
    import os, shutil

    ok = 0
    if os.path.isfile(file_spec):
        # or do other error checking...
        if vtype not in ('copy', 'rename'):
            vtype = 'copy'

        # determine root file name so the extension doesn't get longer and longer...
        n, e = os.path.splitext(file_spec)

        # is e an integer?
        try:
            num = int(e)
            root = n
        except ValueError:
            root = file_spec

        # find next available file version
        for i in xrange(100):
            new_file = '%s_V.%d' % (root, i)
            if not os.path.isfile(new_file):
                if vtype == 'copy':
                    shutil.copy(file_spec, new_file)
                else:
                    os.rename(file_spec, new_file)
                ok = 1
                break
    return ok

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test code (you will need a file named test.txt)
    print VersionFile('test.txt') # File is exists in the directory
    print VersionFile('alpha.txt') # File not exists in the directory
```

Above code is going to work only after downloading the file it will explicitly check and Renaming the file with version if exists.

I want in such a way it should check implicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use glob to check for the file in your target directory:

I havent been able to test this code, consider it as pseudocode for now. But this should do the job once you integrate the method properly into your program.

```
import glob

currentVersion = glob.glob(yourFileName)

if currentVersion == []:                             #checks if file exists
    download and saveAs version-0                                 #saves as original if doesnt exist
else:
    download and saveAs (fileName+(list(currentVersion[0])[-1] + 1)   #if exists, gets the existing version number, and saves it as that number plus one
```