# Python Backup Json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How to add a command for discord py to to backup a JSON file and save as duplicate name.

Example: If i have **amounts.json** file in same directory of bot.py.

i want it to create a back up with duplicate number while it saves everytime.

Comment: You can see an example of how to version file backups here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872708/versioning-file-name-using-python

Comment: One easy thing you can do is to timestamp it.

Comment: [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) might be helpful

Comment: you can add that to your filename. for a more readable timestamp you need to `from datetime import datetime`. And every time you save it, you save it to a filename `'amounts-{}'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%X'))`

Comment: `open('amounts.json', 'w+')` to `'amounts-{}'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%X'))`, its the filename you want to change right, the `open` statement creates a new file for you to write (hence the `w+`) as the second argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your needs are. If you want to save the current `amounts` to `amounts.json` file and overwrite it every time, your code in the question would suffice.

If you want to save the `amounts` to a **different file** so that you can say look back and see the contents of `amounts` at a some previous time, you can add timestamp to your file by

(assuming you had imported `datetime` by `from datetime import datetime`

```
def _save_with_timestamp():
    with open('amounts-{}.json'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%X')), 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)
```

Say, at `2018-11-29-19:00:01` you pressed save and then the contents of `amounts` might be saved to a `json` file named `amounts-2018-11-29-19:00:02.json`.

Comment: are you calling `_save_with_timestamp`?

Comment: you need `from datetime import datetime` at the top to user `datetime`

Comment: Ok finally worked thank you.